# AngularJs Passing complex data to directive

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
<div teamspeak details="{{data.details}}"></div>
```

this is the object structure:

```
data: {
                details: {
                    serverName: { type: 'text', value: 'my server name' },
                    port: { type: 'number', value: 'my port' },
                    nickname: { type: 'text' },
                    password: { type: 'password' },
                    channel: { type: 'text' },
                    channelPassword: { type: 'password' },
                    autoBookmarkAdd: { type: 'checkbox' }
                }
}
```

and I want it to generate a link based on the data inside the `data.details` object. 
**Unfortunately it doesn't work since somehow I cann't access any inner values of the `details` object**, but if I am passing it a simple data structure like:

```
<div teamspeak details="{{data.details.serverName.value}}"></div>
```

I can access it by using `{{details}}`.

**Here is my Directive Code:**

```
App.directive('teamspeak', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: "<a href='ts3server://{{details.serverName.value}}:{{details.port.value}}'>Teamspeak Server</a>",
        scope: {
            details: '@details',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    };
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Read on [Angularjs official site](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) explanation :

> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM
>   attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are
>   strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is
>   assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' },
>   then widget scope property localName will reflect the interpolated
>   value of hello {{name}}. As the name attribute changes so will the
>   localName property on the widget scope. The name is read from the
>   parent scope (not component scope).

So you can send only a string, to pass an object, you need to set-up a bi-directionnal binding using `=`.

```
   scope: {
        details: '=',
    },
```

And your HTML will looks like

```
<div teamspeak details="data.details"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with TypeScript. What I did was create an interface which defines the scope. In that interface I have a custom object. When assigning the interface to the scope, I cannot do `object = '='`, because you cannot assign a string to an object of type `ObjectType`. Any suggestions on how to do this with TypeScript?

Comment: it can also be done using bindings: {}  i'll post an answer once i get it to work :)

Answer (score 39):

Someone asked about how to do it without isolating scope, here is a solution:

`<div teamspeak details="{{data.details}}"></div>`

```
App.directive('teamspeak', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: "<a href='ts3server://{{details.serverName.value}}:{{details.port.value}}'>Teamspeak Server</a>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if(attrs.details){
                scope.details = scope.$eval(attrs.details);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

We can even use `$interpolate` if any values in `attrs.details` should be dynamically set with angular {{...}} expressions...

`scope.details = scope.$eval($interpolate(attrs.details)(scope));`

(don't forget to inject `$interpolate` service into your directive)

**Important Note:**  I have not tested this method with angular 2.

Comment: If you use attrs, you will be having hard time converting this directive to angular 2.  This is just a personal hint.

Comment: thanks @sh977218, I have added a note that this method is not tested with angular 2