# ng-if Directive: What's the issue here?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I'm unable to figure out the mistake that's leading to nothing displaying in my `div`.

**HomeController.js (Controller):**

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.icons = [
        ...
    ];

    $scope.works = [
        {
            title: 'An Artsy Title for an Artsy Image',
            img: 'img/an-artsy-image.png',
            orientation: 'portrait',
            description: "A artsy description here."
        }
    ];
}]);
```

**index.html (Homepage):**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="portfolio">
    <head>
        ...
        <!-- AngularJS Controller -->
        <script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- AngularJS Directive -->
        <script src="js/directives/introIcon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/directives/workExpo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        ...
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="HomeController">
        <div class="container-fluid hero">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid work-wrapper">
            <div class="container work-container">
                <div ng-repeat="work in works">
                    <work-expo info="work"></work-expo>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**workExpo.js (Directive):**

```
app.directive("workExpo", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: 'info',
        templateUrl: 'views/directives/workExpo.html'
    };
});
```

**workExpo.html (Directive Template):**

```
<div class="row" ng-if="info.orientation === 'landscape'">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <img ng-src="{{ info.img }}" class="img-responsive center-block" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3>{{ info.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ info.description }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" ng-if="info.orientation === 'portrait'">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img ng-src="{{ info.img }}" class="img-responsive center-block" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3>{{ info.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ info.description }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is not clear of what is it that I'm missing in the above code which is leading to my code not displaying at all. To my knowledge there is no problem with the controller or directive in general as the other directive in my code (code not shown) is working just fine.

This is what the code becomes post-compilation as per Chrome's code inspector:

```
...
<div class="container-fluid work-wrapper">
    <div class="container work-container">
        <!-- ngRepeat: work in works -->
        <div ng-repeat="work in works" class="ng-scope">
            <work-expo info="work">
                <!-- ngIf: info.orientation === 'landscape' -->
                <!-- ngIf: info.orientation === 'portrait' -->
            </work-expo>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: work in works -->
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Now clearly, it has not returned any DOM elements under `<!-- ngIf: info.orientation === 'portrait' -->` which should rather be the case.

Please let me know in case you need any further details. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `==` instead of `===` to see if that works?

Comment: I don't see the source for `workExpo.js`, all that you provided was the template for that file.

Comment: @JoseM Ah, right. I seemed to have missed that. I've included it now. Please check it.

Comment: @DHP Yep, I did that. Makes no difference.

Comment: does the rest of the data show on the page? (eg. anything else retrieved from info.)

Comment: @lukevp I just included a dummy `p` with `{{ info.orientation }}` but it doesn't show anything, but at the same time `{{ work.orientation }}` shows `portrait`.

Comment: Why not just use work instead of info then?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939569/angularjs-passing-complex-data-to-directive). It looks like you aren't binding your scope correctly.

Comment: Yes. I corrected the scope binding and it worked properly. But I don't understand how it ended up working all the time with the directives I created previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scope binding is incorrect in your directive. You need to construct an object with an `info` property and add 2-way binding of that to the `info` attribute. Yu can do this as so:

```
 scope: {info:'=info'},
```

This creates an `info` property on the scope which evaluates the value of the `info` attribute, i.e. evaluates `work` on the parent scope.

Your full directive code therefore becomes:

```
app.directive("workExpo", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { info: '=info' },
        templateUrl: 'views/directives/workExpo.html'
    };
});
```

and everything else can stay the same.

[Working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t554np88/)

Comment: I corrected the scope binding and it worked properly. But I don't understand how it ended up working all the time with the directives I created previously. Can you clarify why it worked the other times but not this time?

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- ngIf: info.orientation === 'landscape' -->
<!-- ngIf: info.orientation === 'portrait' -->
```

It shows both are not matching so nothing shows

I check your code and it looks good, do one thing to check the value, put following code any where on your page

```
<pre>
   {{ info | json}} - {{ info.orientation | json}} 
</pre>
```

Comment: do you want me to place this inside the directive?

Comment: I did and it just shows a blank `pre` bootstrap box with a hyphen(`-`). I don't know why it is so.

Comment: It means your info value is null, now you know the error so you can fix it, check other lines of code why you are getting null