# passing complex data to ng-directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to build a custom directive in angular; it needs to rielaborate data passed to it before rendering the page, so in the i need to get data passed to my directive through attributes and do some stuff, and finally render the page.

```
.directive('lpcEdiTable', function($interpolate) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "...",
            replace: false,
            scope: {
                collection: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                //here i need to retrieve data
                var myColl = scope.collection; //it's not working
                //do some stuff here on myColl
                scope.collection = myColl;
            }
        };
    });
```

so here's how i use the directive:

```
<lpc-edi-table collection="products"></lpc-edi-table>
```

where `products` is a complex object.

in directive template i use the post elaboration data into `ng-repeat` and other stuff

i tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939569/angularjs-passing-complex-data-to-directive) but i could not retrieve data into `link` function

Comment: What version of angular are you using? There are several ways to define custom tags and I want to answer based on your version.

Comment: i'm using angular 1.6.1 @MichaelKucinski

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of passing an object to a directive

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
.controller("baseController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
        "asd", 
        "asdasd"
    ];
}])

.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<p ng-repeat='item in collection'>{{item.attr}}</p>",
    scope: {
      collection: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      if (!attr.collection) throw new Error("lpc-edi-table directive: 'collection' attribute not found!");
      scope.collection = scope.collection.map(function(a) { return {attr: a} });

      console.log(scope.collection);


    }
  };
});
```

You can call your directive like

```
<my-directive collection="products"></my-directive>
```

DEMO https://plnkr.co/edit/cj4oSPRiNo8iYfinIztT?p=preview

Comment: I need something like this one to work https://plnkr.co/edit/0hX6WRI2zTL6kWeGoB7T?p=preview

Comment: Here is what you need https://plnkr.co/edit/cj4oSPRiNo8iYfinIztT?p=preview

Comment: Now it works! thank you, just one more think... what if my data (`products`) come from an asynchronous Ajax call? i get `scope.collection` being undefined on `link` function in that case

Comment: just put <my-directive ng-if="products" collection="products"></my-directive>

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 1.6, I recommend [using components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). Especially if you don't need to do advanced DOM manipulation.

```
app.component('lpcEdiTable', {
    // $ctrl is controller instance
    template: '<div ng-repeat="object in collection">{{object | json}}</div>',
     bindings: { //custom attributes
         collection: '<' //one way binding. Can also be two way =
     },
     controller: function(){
         //$onInit gets called when the bindings are ready
         this.$onInit = function(){
             // this.collection is now ready
             // safe to manipulate
         };
      }
});
```

This can be used like:

```
<lpc-edi-table collection="products"></lpc-edi-table>
```